# lucia.validateSession() returns null

Tags: mongodb, authentication, sveltekit

here's my issue, I'm using sveltekit + Lucia v3 + MongoDB. followed the instructions for email + password authentication. signup works fine, user and session are added in database, sign in also works fine, createSession and createSessionCookie both return correct  values on sign in. cookies are also stored and  I can see it in devtools , however the validateSession always returns null.
hooks.server.js :

```
import { lucia } from '$lib/server/auth';

export async function handle({ event, resolve }) {
   const sessionId = event.cookies.get(lucia.sessionCookieName);

   if (!sessionId) {
       event.locals.user = null;
       event.locals.session = null;
       return resolve(event);
   }

   const { session, user } = await lucia.validateSession(sessionId);
   //console.log(session, sessionId);
   if (session && session.fresh) {
       const sessionCookie = lucia.createSessionCookie(session.id);

       event.cookies.set.bind(event.cookies)(sessionCookie.name, sessionCookie.value, {
           path: '.',
           ...sessionCookie.attributes
       });
   }

   // if (!session) {
   //     const sessionCookie = lucia.createBlankSessionCookie();
   //     event.cookies.set.bind(event.cookies)(sessionCookie.name, sessionCookie.value, {
   //         path: '.',
   //         ...sessionCookie.attributes
   //     });
   // }
   event.locals.user = user;
   event.locals.session = session;
   return resolve(event);
}
```

sessionId is also correct. the only problem is with validateSession

auth.js

```
import { Lucia } from 'lucia';
import { dev } from '$app/environment';
import { adapter } from './MongoClient';

export const lucia = new Lucia(adapter, {
    sessionCookie: {
        attributes: {
            secure: !dev
        }
    },
    getUserAttributes: (attributes) => {
        return {
            // attributes has the type of DatabaseUserAttributes
            username: attributes.username
        };
    }
});
```

MongoClient:

```
const client = new MongoClient(uri);
await client.connect();

const db = client.db();
const User = db.collection('user');
const Session = db.collection('sessions');
const adapter = new MongodbAdapter(Session, User);

export { db, adapter };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was using Lucia Auth with MongoDB, I encountered an issue while creating a database entry. I initially followed the solution provided in the Lucia docs, which is:

```
await db.collection('user').insertOne({
            id: userId,
            username,
            hashed_password: hashedPasword
        });
```

However, this didn’t work for me. So, I found a solution in pull requests which said to replace  id with _id, as MongoDB uses _id as the default field for the unique identifier in the database. The corrected code is:

```
await db.collection('user').insertOne({
    _id: userId,
    username,
    hashed_password: hashedPassword
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).